# Android Studio Import project issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am having trouble importing a particular project into Android Studio. This project was downloaded from github and extracted. For some reason, when I select import project for this particular project, I get redlines everywhere in the project after doing so. On the final step on the import, I get asked this question. I'm not what it means and I believe this step is causing the error. Here's a screenshot of the question.

[image]

Here's the project I am trying to import.

[image]

Please let me a fix to this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please give us github project link? This error means : Your github project is eclipse project, Follow instructions as per dialog

Comment: if your project have folder ".settings", try to delete it.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android-labs) is the link to the github project. I just downloaded the zip and extracted it